# TensorFlow.JS Integer Multiplication results Decimal Number

Tags: javascript, safari, tensorflow.js

I am just getting started with tensorflow.js and created two simple tensors and trying to perform a multiplication operation on them.

For some reason the result of multiplication of two tensors with floating point integer values is resulting to be a decimal number values for some of the them. This is happening on Safari browser version 11.1.2 and not sure why.

```
// Create new 1D Tensors
const data3 = tf.tensor1d([4, 6, 5, 9]);
const data4 = tf.tensor1d([5, 4, 23, 45]);

// Multipying and Chaining Print Operations
data3.mul(data4).print();
```

**Output on Safari's Web Console:**

Tensor 
    **[20, 23.9999981, 117.3000031, 405.0000916]**

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'd log it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues)

Comment: It works now (0.13.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is expected since the default dtype is `float32` and we upload that data as float to the GPU, which has a lower precision than native JS.

When you create the tensors, you have to explicitly tell that the dtype is `int32`:

```
data3 = tf.tensor1d([4, 6, 5, 9, 11], 'int32');
data4 = tf.tensor1d([5, 4, 23, 45, 23], 'int32');
data3.mul(data4).print();
```

The reason you might get ints in the output for TF.js >=0.13.0 even if the input is float32 is because we started forwarding computation to the CPU when the input is small enough, instead of doing it on the GPU.